# avoiding concurrent insert multiple same id in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am facing a problem in my application. I have a table that one  field name is registration_no. Before inserting a new record i increment registration_no field by 1 and then insert that incremented registration_no in that table. the problem is when some user concurrently insert data some registration_no value has been same. how can i prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a [sequence](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm).

Two caveats:

- The `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature described in the article is non-standard and may give portability issues when moving to a different database.
- If an `INSERT` is aborted, a number from the sequence is consumed still, so you may end up with holes in the sequence. If that is unacceptable, use an autogenerated sequence for the primary (surrogate) key, and add a separate map from that key to the "official" sequence number, enforcing uniqueness in the index of that table.

The alternative is to enforce `UNIQUE`ness in the database, use an appropriate `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` and add application logic to handle failure to `INSERT`.

Comment: Actually registration_no have different range in different category.so i can't give this field auto increment and also i can't give unique because in different year may have same registration no.

Comment: The `UNIQUE` index can be applied to multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the database set the `registration_no` for you, and not do this in code. You can get the `registration_no` in the result of an insert statement and this will solve your concurrency problem.

```
alter table myTable modify column registration_no int auto_increment
```

The result of your query will be the index of the record. **IF** `registration_no` is not the index your will need to query the auto generated `registration_no` based on the returned index id.

Comment: Actually registration_no have different range in different category.so i can't give this field auto increment and also i can't give unique because in different year may have same registration no.

Comment: Then you may need to handle it in a transaction and have the code which writes it handle failures / get a new number.