# Generate unique sequential numbers using SQL in multi-user environment

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, concurrency

I want to generate some unique sequential counters in `tbl1` table, so I wrote following code:

```
using (var dbConnection = CommonDA.GetDbConnection())
{
     var command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
     dbConnection.Open();
     command.CommandText = "insert into tbl1(Counter) select Max(Counter)+1 from tbl1;";
     command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

but sometimes the generated counters are duplicate(because multiple users run the code), is there any mechanism that I generate unique sequential counters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598535/avoiding-concurrent-insert-multiple-same-id-in-mysql

Comment: Also you can define an unique index on the column

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk : I want to use a mechanism that always generate a correct counter.

Comment: Is this for a PK column? Use IDENTITY_INSERT? (MSSQL)

Comment: SQL Server has built in mechanisms to generate unique sequential numbers. Prior to 2012 version you could use an `identity` column, in 2012 and above you can also use `sequence`.

Comment: @Chris: No this is not

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I'm using 2008 version

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use SEQUENCE like this

[Source](https://raresql.com/2013/06/21/sql-server-2012-how-to-generate-a-varchar-sequence-number-using-sequence-object/):

> **Step 1 :**
>
> In this step, we need to create a sample table and a sequence to
>   demonstrate it.
>
> ```
> -- This script is compatibile with SQL Server 2012 and above.
> -- CREATE TABLE
> USE tempdb
> GO
> CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl_sample
> ( [ID] VARCHAR(8) ,
>   [Name] varchar(50)
> CONSTRAINT PK_Employee_EmployeeID
> PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) )
> GO
>
> --CREATE SEQUENCE
> USE tempdb
> GO
> CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Sample_Seq AS
> INT START WITH 1
> INCREMENT BY 1 ;
> GO
> ```
>
> **Step 2 :**
>
> In this step, we need to create a default value for the [ID] column of
>   the above table, and the default value of the [ID] column should be
>   SEQUENCE and add a custom script to make it varchar.
>
> Given below is the script.
>
> ```
> -- This script is compatibile with SQL Server 2012 and above.
> -- CREATE DEFAULT VALUE OF SEQUENCE
> USE tempdb
> GO
> ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_sample
> ADD CONSTRAINT Const_Sample_Seq
> DEFAULT FORMAT((NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.Sample_Seq),'CUS0000#') FOR [ID];
> GO
> ```
>
> **Step 3 :**
>
> Lets insert few records into the table.
>
> ```
> -- This script is compatibile with SQL Server 2012 and above.
> -- Insert records into the table
> USE tempdb
> GO
> INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_sample ([Name])
> VALUES ('Imran'),('Bob'),('Sandra')
> GO
> ```
>
> **Step 4 :**
>
> Once the data has been inserted, you can browse the table and view the
>   [ID] column data that it is either a number or varchar only.
>
> ```
> --Browse Table
> USE tempdb
> GO
> SELECT * FROM tbl_sample
> GO
> --OUTPUT
> ```

Comment: It's worth highlighting the fact that sequence was introduced in 2012 version, so it will not work on older versions.

Comment: It is also noteworthy that there may be gaps in the assigned sequence values.

Comment: But, I'm using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008 there is no [sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) object, but that doesn't mean you can't mimic one, including all the options of a sequence object, except cashing.
However, You must take into consideration the fact that there maybe gaps in the sequence (i.e. 1, 2, 5, 6, 8...)

To do that, you start by creating a table with a single column, that is specified as [identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE tblSequence
(
    Number int identity(1, 1)
)
```

Then, create a stored procedure that will get you the next number:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_NextSequenceNumber
(
    @NextNumber int output
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblSequence DEFAULT VALUES
    SELECT @NextNumber = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```

Now all you have to do to get the next number is simply execute the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @NextNumber int
EXEC stp_NextSequenceNumber @NextNumber output
```

It's also possible to further develop that procedure to handle recycling of the sequence using `truncate table`, that will delete all values from the table and reset the identity column to it's seed:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_NextSequenceNumber
(
    @NextNumber int output
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CurrentNumber int
    SELECT @CurrentNumber = MAX(Number)
    FROM tblSequence

    IF @CurrentNumber >= 10 -- In this example, 10 is the max value of the sequence
        TRUNCATE TABLE tblSequence 

    INSERT INTO tblSequence DEFAULT VALUES
    SELECT @NextNumber = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can use [NEWSEQUENTIALID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx) via SQL Server. It is guaranteed to be unique across space and time.